# using global DB variable inside classes in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, global

How can I use global DB variable inside class?
Let's say I have this in my config.php

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "root", "");
```

and I want to use this $dbh inside class as follows (MyClass.php)

```
class MyClass
{
   public function DoSomething($plogin_id)
   {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_id = :login_id";      
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);    //line 14
        $stmt->bindParam(':login_id', $plogin_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }
}
```

And inside my index.php file I am using this MyClass as follows:

```
include "config.php";
$MyObject = new MyClass();
$login_result = $MyObject->DoSomething("admin");
```

It is giving me error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   prepare() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\admin\includes\classes\MyClass.php
>   on line 14

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to pass the `$dbh` object to `MyClass` somehow. Since you don't want to use globals, I suggests you pass it to `MyClass`'s constructor.

Your MyClass and index.php could look something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   protected $dbh = null;

   public function __construct ( PDO $Pdh )
   {
      $this->dbh = $Pdh;
   }

   public function DoSomething($plogin_id)
   {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_id = :login_id";      
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);    //line 14
        $stmt->bindParam(':login_id', $plogin_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }
}

// in your index.php
$MyObject = new MyClass ( $dbh );
```

This is basically a pattern called dependency injection. See [this excellent tutorial](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/trunk/book/01-Dependency-Injection) for more info on what this is.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce it into your function by using:

```
global $dbh;
```

However, it might be a better idea to add it to the class, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $dbh;

    public function __construct($dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }

    public function DoSomething($plogin_id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_id = :login_id";      
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);    //line 14
        $stmt->bindParam(':login_id', $plogin_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
include "config.php";
$MyObject = new MyClass($dbh); // I'm assuming $dbh is created in config.php
$login_result = $MyObject->DoSomething("admin");
```

Or, introduce it into your function at call time:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function DoSomething($plogin_id, $dbh)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE login_id = :login_id";      
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);    //line 14
        $stmt->bindParam(':login_id', $plogin_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
include "config.php";
$MyObject = new MyClass($dbh); // I'm assuming $dbh is created in config.php
$login_result = $MyObject->DoSomething("admin", $dbh);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most common method:

```
public function DoSomething($plogin_id){
    global $dbh;
    ...
```

Alternative approach:

Create a [singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php) for the database connection. And you use that instead of a global variable:

```
$stmt = MyDBConn::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
```

Comment: You are advocating the use of globals.

Comment: @Alin; I didn't down vote but the problem you actually answer to the title of the question, but let's say the OP misunderstood the problem, his problem is actually not using this

Comment: Did you read the question?! This is **the way** to use global variables in a function. Weather it's a good or a bad thing it's a totally different issue.

Comment: Still, we should be promoting best practises here. Not layzines.

Comment: @Jan Hančič Best practices depend on the situation. If the user is a beginner and doesn't know about the `global` statement don't you think he should learn about that first before moving on to design patterns? This is how bad programmers are born... skipping the basics.

Comment: @Alin: definitly agree. @Jan you are pushing it a bit too far in my opinion

Comment: The only thing he should learn about the `global` keyword is "don't use it". And "dependency injection" isn't exactly rocket science either :) Singeltons are also a bad practise (they have some uses), because they are basically a fancy way of using the `global` keyword.

Comment: @RageZ well excuse me for trying to teach someone to do something properly not half assed.

Comment: @Jan: you don't have to take badly, just I think in programming you have to do the part between having a solution and the good practices. There is so much best practices in the end you end up coding nothing.

Comment: @Jan: I mean you can mention it on your answer but after down voting even if the OP asked for `global` that a bit too much IMHO

Comment: @RageZ I agree with you on the part of "not throwing every good practise you've ever heard of into your code". But this, this is the most basic stuff and I really see no point in teaching somebody to do something wrong. If he'll use globals, it will just screw up his code and he'll have more problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys as it helped me understand the problem. Like Alin told me how to use them which helped me in understanding why they should not be used. So I guess Jan's and Spiny's solution is the best way right!?

Comment: @Ali Yes. That would be the best way to do it.